# How to return all column in groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Given data frame:

| Group | count | status | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 | 2.4 |
| A | 4 | 0 | 7 |
| A | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| B | 3 | 1 | 6 |
| B | 2 | 0 | 7 |

```
df.groupby("Group")["Duration"].max()
```

Expected Result data frame:

| Group | count | status | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 0 | 7 |
| B | 2 | 0 | 7 |

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need `as_index=False` to prevent the group columns from becoming the index in your output.

```
df.groupby("Group",as_index=False)[["count","status","Duration"]].max()
```